# How do I retrieve a hyperlink URL from email within python?

Tags: python, email, url, hyperlink, imaplib

I have the following code to get an HTML email as a email.Message object but am unsure how to proceed from here to find the url of the hyperlink given its display name. I have located the url in the payload(0). In addition the email is a href=3D so it doesnt work if i just copy the link and paste into a browser.

```
import sys
import imaplib 
import getpass
import email
import datetime
import email


M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
M.login('email@email.com','password123')

rv,boxes = M.list()
rv,boxes = M.select('Inbox/Test1')

rv, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')
typ, msg_data = M.fetch('1', '(RFC822)')

msg = email.message_from_string(msg_data[0][1])

url_name = 'Click Here'
html_text = msg.get_payload(0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will show all href in the message...one can update the parseLinks class to choice their individual string they are interested in.

```
import imaplib 
import email
import quopri
import HTMLParser

class parseLinks(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        global global_futures_fair_value
        if tag == 'a':
            for name, value in attrs:
                if name == 'href':
                    print name
                    print value


M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
M.login('email@email.com','password123')

M.select('Inbox/Test1')

rv, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')
typ, msg_data = M.fetch('1', '(RFC822)')

msg = email.message_from_string(msg_data[0][1])

url_name = 'Click Here'
html_text = msg.get_payload(0)

msg = str(msg.get_payload()[0])
msg = quopri.decodestring(msg)

linkParser = parseLinks()
linkParser.feed(msg)
```